# SELECT from one table, INSERT into two other tables based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a Postgres database with 3 tables, say `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to select data from table `A` and loop through each row checking the value in one of the columns and then insert the data into table `B` or table `C` based on the condition.

How can I do this, can some one please post a sample script please. I prefer plpgsql (using PGAdmin3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this, you don't need plpgsql, you don't even need a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) which would allow you to do that in a single SQL statement.

Just run **two plain [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) statements**. Put them in a transaction if you want to make sure all or nothing is applied:

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO B (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   A
WHERE  col_cond = 'something';

INSERT INTO C (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   A
WHERE  col_cond IS DISTINCT FROM 'something';

COMMIT;
```

Comment: ... and if you want to ensure that they're absolutely consistent in the face of concurrent modifications (including `INSERTs`), make sure to `LOCK TABLE A IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before proceeding, making it read-only for the duration.

Answer (score 0):

User cursor for select statement on table A, see this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

Inside the cursor you can check condition and run insert statements on B or C

For code example see this [link](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Postgresql/Part+II+Programming+with+PostgreSQL/Chapter+7.+PLpgSQL/Cursors/)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands:

```
begin;
insert into table_name as select * from table_name2 where Name="?";
commit;
```