# Insert in one table selecting form another base on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider following relationship.

[image]

I am trying to add new row in `Tenants` from `NewRentPayments` if no `Tenants`'s tuple found in `NewRentPayments` base on composite primary keys `houseid` and `apartmentnumber`.

Have a look in my query you will have better idea

```
insert into Tenants(houseid, apartmentnumber, leasetenantssn, leasestartdate, leaseexpirationdate, rent, lastrentpaiddate, rentoverdue)
(
    select n.* from NewRentPayments as n left join Tenants as t 
    on 
    t.houseid = n.houseid 
    and 
    t.apartmentnumber = n.apartmentnumber
    where
    t.houseid is null
    or
    t.apartmentnumber is null
) as newval
(newval.houseid, newval.apartmentnumber, newval.leasetenantssn, now(), NULL, newval.rent, newval.datepaid, 'f');
```

It is giving error on `as newval`.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 12: ) as newval
           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 345
```

*Note:* This is not a simple insert value in one table from another table as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872032/select-from-one-table-insert-into-two-other-tables-based-on-condition). In my case I am inserting some constants/custom values too into the `Tenants` rows while inserting `NewRentPayments` tuples.

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the values as you want to insert in a select.

Try this:

```
insert into Tenants (houseid, apartmentnumber, leasetenantssn, leasestartdate, leaseexpirationdate, rent, lastrentpaiddate, rentoverdue)
select newval.houseid, newval.apartmentnumber, newval.leasetenantssn, now(), null, newval.rent, newval.datepaid, 'f'
from (
    select n.*
    from NewRentPayments as n
    left join Tenants as t on t.houseid = n.houseid
        and t.apartmentnumber = n.apartmentnumber
    where t.houseid is null
        or t.apartmentnumber is null
    ) as newval;
```